# android room best practise - duplicate entities

Tags: android, android-room

I have an existing app that uses a folder-object for it's model. The data is generated on the fly and so there was no persistence. Now i am updating this app to use room as a database, to store said data.

Now i have the `Folder`-Object, AND a `DbFolder`-Object that represents the room-database-object.

Going forward, what is the best practise? Keep both objects and translate between them? Drop the original `Folder` and implement it's methods in the `DbFolder`-Object? Are there downsides to "reusing" the `DbFolder`-Object?

Thanks!

Comment: Unclear what you're doing exactly here. Multiple representations of the same data are sometimes bad (e.g. single source of truth), sometimes desired (when used in different architecture layers to abstract from a specific db - e.g. "dependency direction" https://medium.com/grandcentrix/software-architecture-about-dependencies-4b7258323dac). I guess you might want to keep both as long as your core application doesn't need to know about the db part and the translation into the db version happens in just one place. If you have both everywhere I'd drop one

Answer (score 0):

> Going forward, what is the best practise?

"Best practice" questions are generally perceived as opinion-based and off-topic for the site. That said ...

> Keep both objects and translate between them?

Probably this. See: https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/data-layer#business-models

`DbFolder` - database entity that represents the data actually stored in the DB for a `Folder`.

`Folder` - business logic object that represents a `Folder` object, which may have the same properties as `DbFolder`, but may, and probably will, have more properties and methods used during runtime that don't need to be saved to the DB.

> Drop the original Folder and implement it's methods in the DbFolder-Object?

No. Then you're giving extra responsibility to an object whose sole purpose should be to hold data that is to be stored in / retrieved from a database.

> Are there downsides to "reusing" the DbFolder-Object?

Yes. Inevitably you will have need of properties and methods in different parts of your app that will be convenient to just throw into the DbFolder object. Then that object will bloat making it hard to maintain and extend, and you'll probably run into the problem that the state of the object will sometimes be inconsistent as you add fields that are sometimes populated in some cases where it makes sense and not in other cases where it doesn't.

Mixing buisness-level logic with the DB-level logic will also lead to confusion about what should actually be saved to the DB and what should or shouldn't be loaded from the DB.

Best bet - just keep them separate with simple intermediate functions to convert from one to the other as needed.

Comment: Thanks! I am conflicted about duplicating the objects, but your arguments are reasonable. A rewrite was due because the architecture of the app does not easily allow integration of the database, so i was willing to make bigger changes. However, rebuilding the intermediary is probably the way to go, splitting responsibilities the right way.